# Adding a prefix to SQL result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

can some one please explain how would I add a prefix to column "Name" in my scenario.

I would like to create UNION between two identical tables.
Both contain a field "Name". In the column name I want to add a prefix "TABLE-A-" or "TABLE-B-".

I know i can do this by `N'PREFIX' + Name` in the select, but the problem is that some records already have the prefix and some dont. So by using this would create a double prefix for those records...

Any idea?

Comment: I smell fishy database design... but I would: either replace the existing values with nothing and simply add your prefix to all of them or work with a CASE expression

Comment: Najzero, i have no option. I am integrated to this shitty DB and they performed massive changes without even informing me...

Comment: out of curiosity. Would it breakt anything simply updating all rows bevorehand (aka stripping/repairing all entries with the added prefix again) and then add it in the view/controler again. The CASE will work for sure, but this is just a workaround and the data seems "corrupted" when you have to add the prefix to some but not all because the already have that prefix stored to the data itself

Comment: its more complicated. First of all they wont do it. Second of all, they dont give a shit :) They used to have 1 table for this (among many others) and not they made multiple ... i have to deal with union and views...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression to conditionally add the prefix:

```
CASE WHEN Name like 'A1-%' THEN Name ELSE N'A1-' + Name END
```

Comment: perfect. just what i need.

Answer (score 1):

```
case left(Name, 3) when N'A1-' then N'' else N'A1-' end + Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CASE expressions:

```
CASE WHEN col1 LIKE 'TABLE-A-%' THEN col1 ELSE 'TABLE-A-' || col1 END
```

Alternatively, you could use a UNION of 4 selects:

```
select col1 FROM tab1 WHERE col1 LIKE 'TABLE-A-%'
UNION
select 'TABLE-A-' || col1 FROM tab1 WHERE col1 NOT LIKE 'TABLE-A-%'
UNION
<same stuff for table B>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'TABLE-A'+REPLACE(Name,'TABLE-A','') 
FROM [TABLE-A]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TABLE-B'+REPLACE(Name,'TABLE-B','') 
FROM [TABLE-B]
```

Raj

Comment: This would of course remove **all** occurrences of the prefix used in the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

Add a '+' symbol before the countrycode

```
UPDATE [masters].[country] SET Countrycode = '+' +Countrycode

output:
=========== 
countrycode 
+91,
+355,
....
```

Comment: Please see the 3rd paragraph in the question. The author needs to conditionally add the `'+'`. That's the crux of the question & it isn't included in your answer. :(